# Setting value in a react-dropdown Dropdown's onChange callback throws an error

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, onchange

I am using Dropdown from `react-dropdown` to display some options. Every time a user clicks on a option from list, the value of option should change. As per my code, it changes for the first time. However after choosing second time from list, it gives `TypeError` saying `options.map` is not a function. How can I fix this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Dropdown from "react-dropdown";
import "react-dropdown/style.css";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [options, setOptions] = useState(["one", "two", "three"]);
  const defaultOption = options[""];
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(options.value);
  }, [options.value]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dropdown
        options={options}
        onChange={(value) => setOptions(value)}
        value={defaultOption}
        placeholder="Select an option"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the array of options as the user select an option in drop down

You must concern if `options` must be a state or just the selected value

I've rewrote for you as I imagine is the right way to do it

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Dropdown from "react-dropdown";
import "react-dropdown/style.css";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("");
  const options = ["one", "two", "three"];

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedOption);
  }, [selectedOption]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dropdown
        options={options}
        onChange={({ value }) => setSelectedOption(value)}
        value={selectedOption}
        placeholder="Select an option"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```